# How to convert .ui file to .jui file?

Tags: java, qt, qt-jambi

Does anybody know how to convert a .ui file generated by Qt creator into a .jui file? The documentation says use Qt Generator, but I can't find how to download Qt Generator. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-nt

Comment: what is jui? how is it related to Qt?

Comment: jui is file type outputted by Qt designer which has Jambi’s plugin loaded into it. So this post should be tagged with qt-jambi.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the .ui file using a text editor (I used gedit)
2. Remove the first line of the file which looks something like this:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
3. Delete the whitespace on the top of the file.
4. Modify this line of code : `<ui version="4.0">` to look like this `<ui version="4.0" language="jambi">`  This line should be at the top of the file.
5. Modify the file extension to be .jui

I had to do this and then convert the .jui into a .java file, which took some time to figure out, but if you need to do that and are stuck, I can help.

Comment: I had troubles with getting the plugin for Qt Designer (and getting the Qt Jambi Integration with Eclipse) to work, so I compared a couple .ui and .jui files and the only difference that I could come up with was the lines I mentioned.  I can't say whether this is the "best" way to do it, but it works and isn't much hassle for me.  Writing a helper could be a way to make this conversion even easier.

Comment: Eclipse integration is closed source, so community releases (post 4.5) won’t work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have good grasp about what is going on with the question, but Qt does not have generator (although Jambi does have one, but it does not have support for this conversion from what I know, please fix me if I’m wrong).

Jambi does have a designer plugin that must be loaded into designer so that it can output .jui files. There is a script to launch the designer.

For manual conversion of the file see Ryan’s answer.